# Regularizing stochastic data with conditional forward fill

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm making my first foray into using Pandas 0.24's revamped resampler() objects.  I have a dataframe of quasi-stochastically sampled vehicle speeds.  The logger has a sample period of roughly 1s +/- 100ms when moving, and about 30s when stopped.

The data might look like this:

`0 1 2 0               2 5 7 3 0     3 3 3 1 0`

I'd like to regularize the data to 1s intervals, but without losing my zero-speed intervals.  This is a lot harder than I thought it was going to be, largely because I want to ffill the zero periods, and interpolate the non-zero periods onto the regularized index.

**Questions:**

1. Generally speaking, how would you address this two-part up-fill/interpolate process?
2. Is there a modern analog to the old `resample(how=None)` logic, to let me add regularized timestamps to the index without adding spurious data?
3. Am I stuck looping to fill the zero periods, or is there some kind of apply() magic that will let me do a conditional ffill()?

**Example data:**

```
orig = [0.0,  0.0,  1.5,  2.0,  1.5,  2.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  3.5]
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-12-19 16:50:51+00:00',
               '2018-12-19 16:50:51.400000+00:00',
               '2018-12-19 16:50:57.500000+00:00',
               '2018-12-19 16:50:57.600000+00:00',
               '2018-12-19 16:51:12.500000+00:00',
               '2018-12-19 16:51:16.400000+00:00',
               '2018-12-19 16:51:18.400000+00:00',
               '2018-12-19 16:51:20.400000+00:00',
               '2018-12-19 16:51:22.500000+00:00',
               '2018-12-19 16:51:24.500000+00:00'])
df = pd.DataFrame(orig,index=idx)
df.plot(figsize=(18,4))
```

NB how the plot shows an incorrect speed ramp-up ending at second 57.5.  The speed should be zero until second 57, and ramp up to 1.5 at second 58.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naturally, after working on it for three days, I figured out a reasonable answer about ten minutes after posting.

```
# First create a dummy with the correct index, but containing only the zero periods.
ff = df.asfreq('1s',method='ffill')
dummy1 = ff[ff==0.0]
# Then use 'time' interpolation 
dummy2 = dummy1.combine_first(df).interpolate('time')
# Combine_first adds missing rows from the 2nd dataframe, so resample again
solution = dummy2.asfreq('1s')
```

[image]

The dropped sample at the end is inelegant, but won't be an issue for my purposes; my logs always end with zero.  I'm curious though.  Please post if you have an elegant way to make the initial ffill() include the final sample.